# HTTP request host value syntax in RFC 3986

Tags: http, rfc3986

RFC 3986 says that Host (I'm writing with a capital, to distinguish it as parameter inside HTTP request) value `reg-name` has ABNF syntax `reg-name = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims )`, which includes i.e. signs `+` or `!`, which as far as I know are prohibited in URL authority. Standard states also that

*A host identified by a registered name is a sequence of characters
usually intended for lookup within a locally defined host or service
name registry, though the URI's scheme-specific semantics may require
that a specific registry (or fixed name table) be used instead.  The
most common name registry mechanism is the Domain Name System (DNS).*

And refers to [RFC 1034 section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5), where syntax looks more like I would expect. What's the relation between `reg-name` in HTTP Host value and DNS name syntax? What are technologies which uses  HTTP request Host value different than the most common one (which I understand is just one of many others)?

Comment: Please provide more details. The ABNF for the "Host" header field in HTTP (RFC 7230) referes directly to the "host" ABNF in RFC 3986.

Comment: @JulianReschke right. In RFC 7230 section 5.4 is reference to section 3.2.2 in RFC 3986. And here is "host = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name". Searching for "reg-name" shows ABNF as mentioned in the question, but there is also a part which I don't clearly understand: if I am implementing syntax parser for addresses in the Host field value I would assume, I will see there only syntax looking like i.e. those in the internet URLs, but this ABNF includes signs that are prohibited in URLs - that only my assumption. There is side note, that the addresses I'm probably thinking about are DNS one

Comment: but there are other technologies that uses Host field value and they have their own syntax (that the assumption as well). And my question is whether I understand it correctly, that is: there is general rule for Host field value syntax, which includes IPv4, IPv6 and reg-name, and more precise one for reg-name, which is for certain subset of addresses? (i.e. I never saw Host address exa(mp)le.org, which would be correct looking by "reg-name" rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When HTTP was first created, there were many different network technologies in use. So HTTP was originally written to be transport protocol agnostic. By the mid 1990’s TCP/IPv4 became the only used network technology, together with other protocols used on the internet, like DNS. So HTTP was most likely not developed with expecting only DNS to provide some sort of hostname database, and it’s possible that the HTTP standard accepts a broader range of valid hostnames than the DNS protocol.

To actually answer your question: There is probably no direct relationship. But today there is a de-facto relationship that you'll see only valid DNS names as HTTP Host names on the internet.